# __int64' followed by 'int64' is illegal

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2008, mfc, visual-studio-2017, c99

i have very old project who has been made in visual studio 2008 with windows xp 32 bit.
I am trying to run this project in windows 7 64 bit with visual studio 2017.

i dont know much details about the project.
i know that MFC MBCS pakage was use.

so now i am trying to compile it and got some compilation errors.
the main one is :

__int64' followed by 'int64' is illegal
in the stdint.h file.
the line that get the error is:

```
typedef long long int64_d
```

i check the project and there is no call or use of the stdint header.

i read that it can be because the code build with old version of c++ and now i try to compile with higher version then c++11.

any help will be very appraised.

Thank You!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages and the compiler written for C++ will not support all the constructs of C.

Comment: It's c++99.Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: There is no C++99. There is C99 and C++98.

Comment: Yes, you right. The code was written in old c++ version. But what can i do for making this proj to work well?

Answer (score 0):

Well i figure it out.

the problem was that i am using old libs and dlls(probably made by v100 toolset of VS 2010) , 
so i set the platform toolset to the same version of the visual studio that make those 
libs and dlls - visual studio 2010 v100.

to do that go to :

1. right click on the project
2. properties
3. configuration properties
4. general
5. platform toolset
6. and set it to v100(or other version needed)

now it's work fine!